# How can I have a primary key in a VIEW (a key that doesn't depend on source tables)

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm creating a VIEW out of 3 TABLES. Each TABLE has it's primary key. However, in the VIEW in order to have a primary key, I'll have to use a composite primary key (combination of primary keys of 3 TABLES).

I would however like to add a column in the VIEW as a primary key that is created just for the purpose of the VIEW. As part of the VIEW definition, it should be UNIQUE(autoincrement since it would be mostly an INT). How can I achieve this?

I am using MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use various methods to insert a unique ID to the view data, such as:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, mytable.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, mytable;
```

However this is **not** a primary key, it is not consistant and will change when the data changes.

What exactly do you need a key for?

Comment: Paul, inspired from your thought, I am now concatenating three keys and making a UNIQUE key out of it. Honestly, mine is not a requirement of PRIMARY key but that of a UNIQUE key. Thanks.

Comment: paul, if you apply this to a view, for example, it will not necessarily give you `id` in order.  it gives you a unique identifier, but not in order.

a rather simple solution is to create a temporary table (via insert from a view, for example) that has an autonumber field.  it would force you to recreate table every time your data changed, but that could be easily accomplished in php or java.

Comment: As David Clifton said you can't create a view with `SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, mytable.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, mytable;` You would get a `1351` [error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_view_select_variable)

Answer (score 11):

The highest voted answer using

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id, mytable.*
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, mytable;
```

Is incorrect - you cannot create a view in mysql that uses a sub-select in the FROM. You're only option is to treat a set of columns as a composite key.

Comment: And MySQL doesn't support indexed views, so it was just answering how to get a unique id. Anyway, +1 for pointing it out.

Comment: You cannot even use variables in a select that will create a view. Agreed, the solution is a composite key.

Answer (score 4):

Views don't have primary keys or indexes - the mysql engine will use the indexes and keys defined on the base table(s).

Comment: Your are right. Honestly, mine is not a requirement of PRIMARY key but that of a UNIQUE key. I am now concatenating three keys and making a UNIQUE key out of it.

Comment: Concatenation of PK is the way to go. Please upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

A view is just a stored sub-query. The idea of a PK is irrelevant.

...unless you need an indexed view, in which case you need a Clustered Index on the view (but still not necessarily a Primary Key)

(although, I'm talking SQL Server... I'm not sure how this translates to MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit on what you attempt to do with the primary key. A composed key is crudely nothing more as a concatenation of the fields is composed of. So in order to ''create'' a primary compound key for a view you could concatenate the PKs from the three tables: `concat_ws("+", table1.ID, table2.ID, table3.ID) as PK` inside your view, which is in fact similarly to what most rdbms do when creating compound indexes or keys. This could be used to search in the view and you could even, depending on the storage engine, create an index on this construct improve performance.

Comment: afaik you simply can't create an index on a view in mysql or mariadb