# How do I see all primary keys of a table or column in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

In Mariadb how do I find the PK of a view?

```sql
select table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position
 from information_schema.view_table_usage 
 join information_schema.key_column_usage using (table_schema, table_name) 
 where table_name='the_view' and constraint_name='PRIMARY';
```

fails

SHOW COLUMNS shows

```sql
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
ReservationId   int(10) unsigned    NO      0   
Status  tinyint(1) unsigned     NO      0   
UserId  int(10) unsigned    NO      0   
UserName    varchar(45)     NO      NULL    
StartDate   date    NO      NULL    
EndDate     date    NO      NULL    
Summary     mediumtext  YES         NULL
```

and `DESCRIBE`

```sql
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra   
ReservationId   int(10) unsigned    NO      0   
Status  tinyint(1) unsigned     NO      0   
UserId  int(10) unsigned    NO      0   
UserName    varchar(45)     NO      NULL    
StartDate   date    NO      NULL    
EndDate     date    NO      NULL    
Summary     mediumtext  YES         NULL
```

BTW I use this in a php class generator setting (https://github.com/theking2/kingsoft-persist-db) where having the PK benefits the classe generation process without human intervention

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have a primary key in a VIEW (a key that doesn't depend on source tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971826/how-can-i-have-a-primary-key-in-a-view-a-key-that-doesnt-depend-on-source-tabl)

Comment: views frequently cause more problems than they solve.  avoid them, especially if you are using an ORM or class generator

Answer (score 1):

If its a table, you could use `DESCRIBE tablename`

Alternatively, it is also posible to use the `SHOW COLUMNS` command

I am not sure if there's a better way.

[Link to DESCRIBE command in the official MARIADB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/describe/)

[Link to SHOW COLUMNS command in the official MARIADB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-columns/)

Comment: in mariadb `DESCRIBE view_name` does not disclose the key

Comment: What exactly do you need? the referenced tables from a specific table, which columns are keys in your table or every table with a foreign key to a specific key?

Comment: I need the main key